# Can I use onchange in div element?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to implement `onchange` event in `div` element. 
It seems nothing working. Any ideas?

```
<div id="Range" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%" onchange="update();">
                                 <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
                                 <span></span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                             </div>
```

Also tried using JQuery

```
 $('#Range').change(function () {
        debugger;
        Update();
    });

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
    var end = moment();

    function cb(start, end) {
        $('#Range span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    }

    $('#Range').daterangepicker({
        startDate: start,
        endDate: end,
        ranges: {
           'Today': [moment(), moment()],
           'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
           'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
           'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
           'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
           'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        }
    }, cb);

    cb(start, end);

});
</script>
```

Comment: [The change event is fired for <input>, <select>, and <textarea> elements when a change to the element's value is committed by the user](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change)

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What is changed inside the div and how?

Comment: @empiric, how to do this on my scenario. Please suggest me.

Comment: You haven't told us what your scenario is, so hard to tell what you would need

Comment: Maybe use onclick?

Comment: I assume you are referring to your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50919511/4202224), if that's still the same problem, have a look at the [events](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#events) the daterangepicker provides

Comment: @empiric, when user selects the date then I want to fire the change event ` Update();` which I mentioned in my question.

Comment: @empiric, can you please help me. `When the page loads, by default `Last 7 Days` is selected in `daterangepicker`. But What I want is that when page first loads, it should skips ` if (label == "Last 7 Days"){` and when user manually selects it then it should hit the click event.

Comment: @empiric,the script is `$(function() { 
        var start = moment().subtract(7, 'days');
        var end = moment();
        var label = 'Last 7 Days' 
         function cb(start, end, label) {             
                 if (label == "Last 7 Days")
                {
                    $(this).on('click', function () {
                        Update();
                    })                
                else
                {
                    Update();
                }            
            }  
    });`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly change? what value will you change in the div?

You can use the click.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#Range', function(){
    $(this).html('click 123');
      // debugger;
      // Update();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Range">click</div>
```

Comment: Please provide me solution related my code. As I am using daterangepicker so please use the same.